# How to set up custom block in layout file?

Tags: xml, magento, layout

I can't setup block in advancedSearch.xml layout. My extension has name **Rockstar_Chatattributes**.
Here is my config.xml(just necessary nodes):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Rockstar_Chatattributes>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Rockstar_Chatattributes>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <chatattributes>
            <class>Rockstar_Chatattributes_Block</class>
        </chatattributes>
    </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <chatattributes>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Rockstar_Chatattributes</module>
                <frontName>advancedSearch</frontName>
            </args>
        </chatattributes>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <chatattributes>
                <file>advancedSearch.xml</file>
            </chatattributes>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

**Here is advancedSearch.xml:**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<chatattributes_index_index>
<reference name="content">
<block type="chatattributes/john" name="john" as="john" template="chatattributes/john/view.phtml" />
</reference>
</chatattributes_index_index>
```

here /app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/template/chatattributes/john/view.phtml is locating my template

here is my block(app/code/local/Rockstar/Chatattributes/Block/John.php):

```
class Rockstar_Chatattributes_Block_John extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
public function logic() {
    echo 'block has been included';
}
}
```

So now my block just ignoring. 
but when i type core/template instead chatattributes/john in advancedSearch.xml, the text in template displaying fine.

Comment: give me all code of advancedSearch.xml,

Comment: all code is in a question, just forgot add </layout> tag

Comment: looks everything perfect..how you are calling that block?

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout version's value. It is of `0.1.0` in `advancedSearch.xml` and `config.xml's version` is of `1.0.0`. I think here might be the mistake. The versions of these two files must have to be same. Change those valuesin any one of the file.